# Drop Multi-index and auto rename columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, multi-index

I'd like to transform the below output into:

- remove the multiindex(it should just be one row of index)
- numbered accordingly Job 1, Job Effective Date 1, Job 2, Job Effective Date 2, etc.
- I'd like this to be scalable if I choose to add or remove additional variables, I'd like to not have to modify the code to accommodate it (this is example is scaled down).

**Some Data:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = {'Name': ["Joe", "Joe", "Joe","Jane","Jane"],
        'Job': ["Analyst","Manager","Director","Analyst","Manager"],
        'Job Eff Date': ["1/1/2015","1/1/2016","7/1/2016","1/1/2015","1/1/2016"]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Name', 'Job', 'Job Eff Date'])

def tgrp(df):
    df = df.drop('Name', axis=1)
    return df.reset_index(drop=True).T

df2.groupby('Name').apply(tgrp).unstack()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution with `join`:

```
df.columns = [' '.join((col[1], str(col[0] + 1))) for col in df.columns]
print (df)
        Job 1 Job Eff Date 1    Job 2 Job Eff Date 2     Job 3 Job Eff Date 3
Name                                                                         
Jane  Analyst       1/1/2015  Manager       1/1/2016       NaN            NaN
Joe   Analyst       1/1/2015  Manager       1/1/2016  Director       7/1/2016
```

If need remove index name, use [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
df.columns = [' '.join((col[1], str(col[0] + 1))) for col in df.columns]
df = df.rename_axis(None)
print (df)
        Job 1 Job Eff Date 1    Job 2 Job Eff Date 2     Job 3 Job Eff Date 3
Jane  Analyst       1/1/2015  Manager       1/1/2016       NaN            NaN
Joe   Analyst       1/1/2015  Manager       1/1/2016  Director       7/1/2016
```

How it work:

List comprehension convert `MultiIndex` to `list` of `tuples`, which are joined by `join`, but first is necessary add `1` and convert `int` to `str` of each first item of tuples:

```
print ([col for col in df.columns])
[(0, 'Job'), (0, 'Job Eff Date'), 
 (1, 'Job'), (1, 'Job Eff Date'), 
 (2, 'Job'), (2, 'Job Eff Date')]
```

Output is list of strings, which is assigned to column names:

```
print ([' '.join((col[1], str(col[0] + 1))) for col in df.columns])
['Job 1', 'Job Eff Date 1', 'Job 2', 'Job Eff Date 2', 'Job 3', 'Job Eff Date 3']
```

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
df3.columns = ['{} {}'.format(col[1], col[0]) for col in df3.columns]
```

if you are OK with 0-based indexing. Otherwise change to `col[0] + 1`

Comment: Brilliant! It works, but I'm not sure how... I tried to break it apart. I think the brackets are a replace function, but why only two of them? Also, .format(col[1]--is that referring to the level down from the top of the multiindex? Lastly, how does it get rid of the top level index?

Comment: @Christopher Lots of questions! I'll do my best. 1. The brackets are a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), one of Python's dreamiest features. Or do you mean the curly braces? They + the `.format()` function are used for [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) in Python. 3. When you iterate through df3.columns, you get the name of each hierarchy as a tuple for each column. I am concatenating them to a single name, by using `str..format()`.